# Can't execute page objects pattern with protractor properly

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I've been trying to adapt my test code within page objects pattern. But i'm having some hard time with this.

I have the following code:

*This is my page objects file*

```
PageObjects = function() {

    var preenchePsafe = dvr.findElement(by.id('global-search'));
    var opcaoPsafe = dvr.findElement(by.css('#search > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a'));


    this.pesquisarPsafe = function(pesquisa) {

        //dvr.findElement(by.id('global-search')).sendKeys(pesquisa);
        preenchePsafe.sendKeys(pesquisa);
        opcaoPsafe.click();

    };

    };

module.exports = PageObjects;
```

*This is my spec file*

```
var pageObjectsModule = require('./page.js');

describe('PSafe Home', function () {
    var pageObject;

    beforeEach(function () {
        pageObject = new pageObjectsModule();
        isAngularSite(false);
        handlePromise = dvr.getAllWindowHandles();
    });

    it('Pesquisar PSafe', function () {

        dvr.get('http://home.psafe.com/');
        pageObject.pesquisarPsafe('PSafe');

    });

});
```

When i comment the lines

```
 var preenchePsafe = dvr.findElement(by.id('global-search'));
 var opcaoPsafe = dvr.findElement(by.css('#search > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a'));

 preenchePsafe.sendKeys(pesquisa);
 opcaoPsafe.click();
```

And uncomment the line

```
 //dvr.findElement(by.id('global-search')).sendKeys(pesquisa);
```

My test works properly. But i dont want to do like this, it makes no sense use page objects like this. Since i'm a beginner in javascript and jasmine, i think it may be an code strucute issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that part of your stack trace says 
`TypeError: object is not a function`

because in the beforeEach function of your spec file, you're trying to instantiate pageObject as a new instance of the pageObjectsModule *function*, but pageObjectsModule is defined as an *object* in your first line.

```
var pageObjectsModule = require('./page.js'); 

describe('PSafe Home', function () {
    var pageObject;

    beforeEach(function () {
        pageObject = pageObjectsModule; // This line should fix the problem.
        isAngularSite(false);
        handlePromise = dvr.getAllWindowHandles();
    });

    it('Pesquisar PSafe', function () {

        dvr.get('http://home.psafe.com/');
        pageObject.pesquisarPsafe('PSafe');

    });

});
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
var pageObject = require('./page.js'); // define the pageObject object as soon as you require it.

describe('PSafe Home', function () {
   // var pageObject;

    beforeEach(function () {
     // pageObject = new PageObjectsModule(); // now you don't need this line
        isAngularSite(false);
        handlePromise = dvr.getAllWindowHandles();
    });

    it('Pesquisar PSafe', function () {

        dvr.get('http://home.psafe.com/');
        pageObject.pesquisarPsafe('PSafe');

    });

});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping. Here's what i got doing this: TypeError: Cannot call method 'pesquisarPsafe' of undefined

Comment: right, sorry. you should also delete the line declaring `var pageObject;` I've fixed this in my answer

Comment: I saw that before, here's what i got: TypeError: Object function () { } has no method 'pesquisarPsafe' 
at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\QARJ\WebstormProjects\ProtractorPiloto\piloto.js:15:20)

Comment: try making pageObject global: `pageObject = require('./page.js');` instead of `var pageObject = require('./page.js');`

Comment: in your `page.js` file: change the last line to `module.exports = new PageObjects();`

Comment: Got it, turns out it was a mix of your solution with Andres's solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`dvr` is not defined in the page object. Either you need a:

```
var dvr = require('some/path.js')
```

At the top of your page object file or inside the constructor.

Also, I would recommend you to use `element(by.css())` or `$()` instead of dvr.findElement(by). For example:

```
// $() is the same as element(by.css())
var preenchePsafe = $('global-search'));
// You can chain element calls.
var opcaoPsafe = $('#search > ul').$$('li').get(1).$('a');
```

Comment: Hello, i've declared `dvr` in my config.js. Actually, i'm testing a non-angular application, i tought that `element` instead `findElement` were only for angular applications. Isnt that correct?